# trigger alert when clicking on a google drop down item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-api

So I'm using a Google API to show a list of places in a dropdown when I'm typing in an address.

When I click on one of the options/address on the dropdown I want an alert to trigger that says hi. What's the best way to do this?

More info:

Each item in the drop-down has a class of `'pac-item'` and is inside a div of `'pac-container'` :

```html
<div class="pac-container pac-logo" style="width: 601px; position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 70px; display: none;">
  <div class="pac-item"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">S</span>ão Paulo</span><span>State of São Paulo, Brazil</span></div>
  <div class="pac-item"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">S</span>an Francisco</span><span>CA, USA</span></div>
</div>
```

So I've been trying to get the Elements by there class name and then when you click on one of them it should alert 'hi '

However, since the items in the dropdown don't load in until you click on the input I think it's causing a problem when the page loads and Javascript tries to get the elements by their class name.

What's the best way to fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="distance_form">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Origin: </label> <input class="form-control" id="from_places" placeholder="Enter a location" />
          <input id="origin" name="origin" required="" type="hidden" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>

      $(function () {
        // add input listeners
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
          var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById("from_places")
          );
        });
         console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("pac-item"))

         let googleDropDown = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-item")

         googleDropDown.addEventListener('click', alert)

         function alert(){
           alert('hi')
         }
      });

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Wrapping it inside the `google.maps.event.addDomListener` allows me to log the items to the console but also results in the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that current elements and future elements will handle your click event with the .on() function

```
  $(function () {
    // add input listeners
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
      var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById("from_places")
      );
    });

     $("body").on("click", ".pac-container > .pac-item", function() {
         alert('hi');
     });
  });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186894/discussion-on-answer-by-lajos-arpad-trigger-alert-when-clicking-on-a-google-drop).